# player image disapearing when not moving / "load_map" not lading fast enough

Tags: qb64

the code works, but the screen is getting cleared when i'm not moving, causing the player to disappear when you don't move.

ive tried doing `wait .5, .5`. and just not using `CLS`

I also think that the `CLS` in the `DO LOOP` is preventing the map from loading

```
RANDOMIZE TIMER
SCREEN _NEWIMAGE(800, 600, 32), 2
x = 0
y = 0

DIM SHARED x AS INTEGER
DIM SHARED y AS INTEGER
DIM SHARED u AS INTEGER
DIM SHARED o AS INTEGER
DIM SHARED Keypress AS STRING
DIM SHARED player AS LONG
DIM SHARED zombie AS LONG
DIM SHARED map_data(800, 600) AS INTEGER


SCREEN _NEWIMAGE(800, 600, 32)
u = INT(RND * 450) + 50
o = 100

player = _LOADIMAGE("Sprites\3.png")
house = _LOADIMAGE("Sprites\2.png")
zombie = _LOADIMAGE("Sprites\4.png")

TIMER ON
ON TIMER(.2) enemyai

DO
    _PUTIMAGE (x, y), player

    DO
        Keypress = UCASE$(INKEY$)

        IF LEN(Keypress) > 1 THEN Keypress = RIGHT$(Keypress, 1)
    LOOP UNTIL Keypress > ""

    CLS


    SELECT CASE Keypress
        CASE "W", "H": y = y - 10 'Up
        CASE "A", "K"
            x = x - 10 'Left
        CASE "S", "P": y = y + 10 'Down
        CASE "D", "M": x = x + 10 'Right
        CASE "Q", CHR$(27): END 'Q or Esc Ends prog.
    END SELECT
    _PUTIMAGE (x, y), player
    load_map
LOOP


SUB enemyai
    CLS
    o = o + 1
    _PUTIMAGE (o, u), zombie

END SUB


SUB load_map
    OPEN "map.dat" FOR INPUT AS #1
    FOR a = 0 TO (780 \ 16)
        FOR b = 0 TO (580 \ 10)

            INPUT #1, map_data(a, b)

        NEXT
    NEXT


    CLOSE #1

END SUB
```

map.dat attached and sprites.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13LjenIPDfP34BActYdM19l9ljeo6F9xW?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

ok so i figured it out

```
SELECT CASE Keypress
        CASE "W", "H": y = y - 10 'Up
        CASE "A", "K"
            x = x - 10 'Left
        CASE "S", "P": y = y + 10 'Down
        CASE "D", "M": x = x + 10 'Right
        CASE "Q", CHR$(27): END 'Q or Esc Ends prog.
    END SELECT
    _PUTIMAGE (x, y), player
    load_map
LOOP


SUB enemyai
    o = o + 1
    _PUTIMAGE (o, u), zombie

END SUB
```

i had to gt rid of the `cls` in `enemyai`